# Loading a dump file(.dbo file) into mariadb database

Tags: mysql, dump, mariadb, postgresql-9.2

I have a `.dbo` file and I need to load the dump file into mariadb. How it is possible? 
In MySQL I tried like this :

`mysql -u root -p dbname -e " source path/test.dbo"`

But the same is not works with MariaDB.

Have any idea??? How to so the same in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved, the port number in the ini file is changed to default, now it is working fine with the same command in th mysql. The command I used is :

> mysql -u root -p sampledb -e "  source path/xxx.dbo"

Answer (score 0):

Same as mysql only we should use

```
  mysql -u root -ppassword dbname < test.dbo
```

[See the reference here](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/mysqldump/)

let me know if you face any issues